# How to include all child entities when querying a context with a Where expression using Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I created a generic repository that handles querying my entities.

When I call this:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery()
        {
           return _context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
        }
```

I get back the entire entity including all child entities.

When I call this:

```
public TEntity GetById(Guid id)
        {
            return GetQuery().Where(e => e.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

I have to specify what child entities to include.

Is there a way to get back ALL child entities without having to write includes for each entity?

Comment: Lazy loading usually controls whether or not child objects or automatically returned (LazyLoading == true) or manually included (LazyLoading == false).

Comment: Funny thing is, Lazy Loading is set to true. If it wasn't on, wouldn't my first, GetQuery(), not contain child entities?

Comment: Might depend on where the functions are declared I guess but yeah is strange that one LazyLoads and the other doesn't which is why I only added a comment rather than an answer as I thought you would know the obvious.

Comment: I apprecaite it, really, I do. It made me look into that, anyway. You never know if I had set it to false anywhere. As you can see in the code, I call the GetQuery and then supply a where clause. I'll have to profile the query and see what happens.

Comment: You don't "get back the entire entity including all child entities" in your first example. You get back nothing more than an `IQueryable<T>`. What are you doing now with this IQueryable? And why are you calling `AsQueryable()`? DbSet<T> is an IQueryable implementation anyway...

Comment: The AsQueryable() was left there because of testing. You are correct, it is already implementing IQueryable. What I meant, was, if I call my GetQuery() method, I get back a collection<T> entities I can query including child entities. I see the all the data. If my data is available in the GetQuery() method, why once I actually query it, are my child entities empty?

Comment: Where do you "see all the data"? I mean, an IQueryable isn't a collection in memory, it's just a query specification. Do you see the data in the debugger's watch window (it executes the query), or do you actually call `.ToList()` or `FirstOrDefault()` without a `Where` or something? What happens with the second query in your example if you simply omit the `Where`, so only: `return GetQuery().FirstOrDefault();`? If I understand correctly you say lazy that loading doesn't work anymore as soon as you have a Where clause in your query?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I do convert it to a list. I will update the question.  As soon as I add a Where clause, the child entities are not being loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy loading is enabled by default. This means that the collections will be loaded *when* you access them, not when you retrieve the parent object e.g.

```
foreach (var parent in repo.GetQuery()) {
    foreach (var child in parent.Children) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

If you wish to eagerly load your entities you could subclass your generic repository and override the methods where you wish to use the `Include` lambda. Alternatively there [is an Include method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696450%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) that accepts a string list of associations to include, which you could expose on your generic repository.

Update:

Not quite sure why you gave my answer -1 but as further clarification.

You stated regarding your GetQuery() method:

> I get back the entire entity including
>   all child entities.

The child entities are lazily loaded, whether you access the collections in debug or output them on your page.

The single query *should* work, with lazy loading enabled.

And AFAIK, with lazy loading disabled, this doesn't mean that all the collections are loaded automatically, quite the opposite, you have to explicitly load them by calling Include.

Comment: In the comments, above, I state Lazy Loading is enabled. Also, in my question I state I get back the child entities when I run the GetQuery method. Once I add the where expression I do not get back child entities. I further ask if I can get back all child entities without using the include method.

Comment: @DDiVita But Lazy Loading enabled is what doesn't load them. If it's set to eager loading (lazyload off) then when you hit that row it should fetch everything associated with it. If it's not, something isn't working right.

Comment: @DDiVita - I was answering the question in your comments. You asked "If it wasn't on, wouldn't my first, GetQuery(), not contain child entities" - I answered accordingly - "Only when you access the collection" - hence LAZY loading. So you either leave it on and iterate the collections or you eagerly load them with Include. So, why the -1?

Comment: @Ben - I apologize, but you are still not making any sense to me. Lazy loading is enabled for the entire context. In my comments above, I was asking "If I really had it turned off, why would I still get all my child entities." This meant, I most likely had it turned on. I do not wish to eager load. I am not sure where the disconnect is or perhaps you are misunderstanding what I am try to say?

Comment: @Ben - My question is: "Is there a way to get back ALL child entities without having to write includes for each entity?" I set the -1 because I thought you didn't read the whole post. If I set lazy loading to OFF, then my GetQuery doesn’t bring back child entities, as expected. If I keep it at the default, ON, then everything works on the GetQuery, until I call the Where expression. So, if there is an issue, what could it be?

Comment: @DDiVita - how are you testing this behaviour? In short, no you can't eagerly load child entities without explicitly calling Include. I assume you are trying to access the child collection outside of the repository, so how are you managing your DbContext lifespan?

Comment: @Ben - I created a unit test for my repo. I am managing my context through a UnitOfWork object. I first instantiate the UoW then pass that to a repo object. All this code is in the [TestInitialize] section. So it is always available. I have a test case to call the GetQuery(). I get back the IQueryable<MyEntity> and a collection of my entities and all of the child entities. I have another test case that calls the GetById. I get back the entity, but I have to use the include method to get back child entities. I guess I don't understand why. Wouldn't lazy loading include them?

Comment: @DDiVita, you should post the test that is failing. As I've said already, lazy loading doesn't include *anything*. It is only when you attempt to access the child collection that a second query is made to the database. I'll post a test demonstrating the *expected* behaviour when I get chance, as this comment thread is getting a bit long now.